# Can't get Account field values in Postman using REST API

Tags: rest-api

I am trying make a simple query to get a Salesforce Account value, but couldn't get it to work using Postman.

The API I am using:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm

Request URL:

https://MyInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/myObjectId?fields=AccountNumber

In the header I am providing the Authorization Header.  I know for a fact it's not because of my authorization bearer because when I try to describe the Account object it does work:

https://MyInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account

Is there like a special permission I need to give to actually read object value that I don't know about or is there another setting that I am missing?

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Your error message shows three spurious URL-encoded characters following the Salesforce Id. Not quite sure why that might produce this specific behavior but it definitely looks off.

Comment: workbench is handy for this stuff as it handles the auth for you

Comment: @DavidReed OMG you right, don't know where they came from and I retyped the URL and it works!